# Python dependency on Gnome Builder

Tags: python, linux, gtk, flatpak, gnome-builder

I am learning how to create GTK applications in python and I am using Gnome Builder IDE installed through flatpak.
I wanted to use the python package `requests` in my application, so I added:

```
{
    "name": "pip-install",
    "buildsystem": "simple",
    "build-options": {
      "build-args": [
        "--share=network"
      ]
    },
    "build-commands": [
        "pip3 install requests"
    ]
}
```

To my `modules` list inside the flatpak `.json` file of the project.
When I try to build the project I get the following error when the command runs pip:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/idna-2.9.dist-info'
```

One solution would be the dependency being installed on user space, but how to do that?

Comment: `pip3 install --user requests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used this snippet before:

```
    {
        "name": "requests",
        "buildsystem": "simple",
        "build-options": {
          "build-args": [
            "--share=network"
          ]
        },
        "build-commands": [
            "pip3 install --prefix=/app --no-cache-dir requests"
        ]
    }
```

The `/app` directory is writable and the rest of your application should be there as well.